# Get index of middle of string

Tags: groovy

I got a string like this

```
def list1 = "magazine, news, friend, Steve, other: movie"
def list2 = "cartoon, music, magazine, news, friend, Peter, other: movie"
```

How can I get index of friend, the text may change, but `friend` do not change. Steve is friend name, it may be Jack or Andy or some name.
Any solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for "Steve" specifically? Then you could just use `indexOf`.

Comment: don't get your point. Why don't use `indexOf` directly?

Comment: So I mean that friend does not change, Steve is friend name. It may be Peter or Andy, etc. The purpose of this is I have a list of check box on html, so friend is checkbox and Steve is text field next to check box. I'd like to get that value.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the index of "Steve"? Are you trying to find the item in the list that comes after "friend"? Please post some examples of possible inputs and what the result should be.

Comment: Sir, it means that how can I get index of friend in list1 and list2 when I split(',')

Comment: If you're looking for the index of "friend", why does `list1.split(',').indexOf("friend")` not do what you want? If you're looking for the index of "Steve" in the first case and "Peter" in the second case, why doesn't `list1.split(',').indexOf("friend") + 1` do what you want?

Comment: Sir, @MattGiles why 
`print list1.split(',').indexOf('friend')` -> **not work**
`def a = ['a','b','c','d']`
`print a.indexOf('c')` -> **this works.**

Comment: Because `split()` results in a String Array on which you cannot use `indexOf()`. you can use `tokenize()` instead as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def list1 = "magazine, news, friend, Steve, other: movie"
def list2 = "cartoon, music, magazine, news, friend, Peter, other: movie"

assert [list1, list2].collect { it.tokenize(/,/)*.trim().indexOf('friend') } == [2, 4]
```